# FreeBSD running in Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, freebsd, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I'd like to install FreeBSD 8.0 in a Hyper-V VM but I get a kernel panic whenever I try to boot the install ISO.  I've tried both i386 and amd64; with and without APIC enabled; with and without processor features disabled in Hyper-V.  Is it necessary to use the procedure in the Handbook for Xen domU?

Does anyone has experience with this configuration?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/hyperv-supported-guest-os.aspx), there are no BSDs supported on Hyper-V.  You may want to look in to a another virtualization solution if you need to run BSD VMs.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Hyper-V on an AMD machine, try this command:

```
set hw.clflush_disable=1
```

This worked for me using Hyper-V on an AMD machine with FreeBSD 8 (I believe, it's a pfSense 2.0.1 distribution)

Also, use legacy network adapters as normal ones will not work.

There is also a problem with the network drivers I found in BSD where they wouldn't work until you reset them with a command like this:

```
ifconfig de0 down
ifconfig de0 up
```

optionally with this command, if you need DHCP:

```
dhclient de0
```

Check out the following links for my sources:

- [Boot Troubleshooting](http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Boot_Troubleshooting)
- [PfSense on Hyper-V](http://dekapitein.vorkbaard.nl/tech-1/pfsense)

Answer (score 1):

FreeBSD 8 works flawlessly on my setup. Remove the NIC installed by default and ad a legacy nic. You should be good to go after that.

Comment: Did you install through Hyper-V or mount an existing install?  Is it i386 or AMD64?

Comment: I was able to get 7.2-RELEASE to work in AMD64.  Couldn't get 8.0 working.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think any BSD is supported on hyper-v. The only OS that works well is RHEL/CentOS (and windows of course)

I have however, run FBSD4-7 on vmware, and have also run v6 and v7 on kvm-qemu with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can get FreeBSD to work in Hyper-V but I wouldn't recommend it. I've had LOTS of issues, the most annoying was the machine "shutting down" for months. The only way to fix this issue, was to reboot the whole hyper-v box.

To that end, there aren't many Linux distros supported by Hyper-V either. If you want to run a unix-like OS, you should use vmware, xen, virtualbox, or something along those lines.